# No matching client found for package name when set applicationidsuffix

Tags: android, gradle, build

I want to create 4 different apk for same device

**devrelease

**devdebug

**prodrelease

**proddebug

but I get log below when I compile

> No matching client found for package name 'com.example.dev.debug'

```
 buildTypes {

        release {
        }

        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        dev {
            applicationIdSuffix '.dev'
        }
        prod {
        }
    }
```

How can I solve this problem.

Comment: you are using google services with it's JSON, which has to have all the packages you are using to build

Comment: problem solved when I add the debug config in google json file. tx @VladyslavMatviienko

Answer (score 1):

You should add the same package to your Google services JSON file.